# Does $SO(n)$ lie in any $(n^2-1)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbf R^{n^2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, differential-geometry, lie-groups

The matrix group $SO(n)$ can be treated as a submanifold of $\mathbf R^{n^2}$. Does it lie in any $(n^2-1)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbf R^{n^2}$?

For $n=2$ the answer is yes because $SO(2)$ lies in the span of the identity matrix and $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$. How about for $n>2$? Thanks.

Comment: I know this fact, may I ask how to proceed?

Comment: @uniquesolution This doesn't help. The curve $(t, t^2, t^3, \dots, t^n) \in \mathbb R^n$ is 1-dimensional, yet hardly lies in any proper subspace.

Comment: @lisyarus -- good point. So, what do you think is the answer to the OP's question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the linear hull of $SO(n)$ for $n>2$ is the whole $M_{n^2}(\mathbb R)$. Thus, the answer is **no**, there does not exist an $n^2-1$-dimensional subspace that contains $SO(n)$ for $n>2$.

Several proofs with further discussions may be found in [this mathoverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310316/is-the-linear-span-of-special-orthogonal-matrices-equal-to-the-whole-space-of-n).